# How to join 2 Xpath query?

Tags: php, xpath

I have html structure like below (this I just take little from my html):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     //some content here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
     //some content here
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract content from class **col-md-4** and class **col-md-8** and I have got what I want with this code:

```
$test1 = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class,"col-md-4")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$test2 = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class,"col-md-8")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$test = $test1.$test2;
```

If I write code like this

```
$test = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class,"row")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I can get the result but, it's not the result in class**col-md-4** and class **col-md-8** because I have many class **row** in my html.

and this code not work

```
$test = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class,"row")]//div[contains(@class, "col-md-4")]//div[contains(@class, "col-md-8")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

With my first code that it worked, is there any to join it into one Xpath query?

Thank in advance for help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [concat](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat) to combine the results of 2 or more strings, each of which can be the results of an xpath selector:

```
concat(//div[contains(@class,"col-md-4")], //div[contains(@class,"col-md-8")])
```

[Example here](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifph)